# Schengen Applicant Form: Question on Residence Status

Tags: visas, schengen

Field 18 on the Schengen Visa Form inquires as follows:

**Residence in a country other than the country of current nationality:
No
Yes. Residence permit or equivalent ................. No. ................... Valid until .................**

Our status is as follows:
We were issued PR cards by Canada last year, but we still haven't moved and reside in our country of nationality.

Should I still fill in YES, so as to give card details since NO has no corollary question?

Answer (score 1):

The question asks for your *current*, actual residence.

However, if you're planning to move to Canada, then in the nature of things your ties to your home country are going to be weak. It will probably help your chances to enclose documentation of the Canadian PR anyway, even though you answer "no" to that particular question. Having legal access to an affluent country like Canada is an excellent reason why it wouldn't be economically attractive for you to become an illegal immigrant in a Schengen country.

Comment: This is interesting. On the one hand, I will be disclosing wealth and tax statements to stress my ties with my country. And on the other, the PR card info, which even though is legal and positive, serves to weaken my ties.

Comment: @Saadia: Well, _by definition_ in this context "ties" is whatever _prevents_ you from moving away from the country. If you have concrete plans to move to Canada soon, then such ties cannot really exist -- so what you document there would be something that _look like_ ties but actually aren't.

Comment: @Saadia Canadian PR cards may weaken one aspect of your case but they may strengthen another aspect of it.  You don't necessarily have to have strong ties to your country of citizenship; the main thing is to have a reason to leave the Schengen area.

Comment: So both your votes are in favour of submitting them then, correct?

Comment: @Saadia Have you been to Canada using your PR cards? The recommended course of action probably depends on why you haven't moved yet, on whether and when you plan to move, and on what you have actually done in Canada (if anything) since receiving your authorization to take up residence there.  You haven't disclosed any of this, so it is hard to say.

Comment: We haven't moved yet and do not plan to go for another year at least owing to an ailing family member entirely dependent on us.